# Calculating Electrostatic Energy from Capacitance Matrix

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, potential-energy, capacitance

Let's say I have two spherical conductors and I put some charge on each. As I understand it, the electrostatic energy $W$ in the fields will be equal to
$$W = \frac{1}{2}C_{11}V_1^2 + \frac{1}{2}C_{22}V_2^2+C_{12}V_1V_2$$
where the $C_{ij}$ are the elements of the capacitance matrix and $V_i$ is the potential at the $ith$ conducting surface.  Is this correct?  If it is, am I able to express this just in terms of the charges I put on the spheres and not the potentials?

Comment: The energy of the two conductor system can be found easily if you just know their capacitance, $C$. The energy would then be $W = \frac{1}{2} \frac{Q^2}{C}$, where $Q$ is the charge on the conductor.

Comment: But what if the charges are different on the two conductors?